# My ajax wont work to change the html inside

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, authentication

My HTML code

```
<form class="form-signup" id="usersignup" name="usersignup" method="post" action="createuser.php">
        <h2 class="form-signup-heading">Register</h2>
        <input name="newuser" id="newuser" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
<br>
        <input name="password1" id="password1" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <input name="password2" id="password2" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat Password">

        <button name="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>

        <div id="message"></div>
      </form>
```

This is the ajax

```
    success: function(html){
        var text = $(html).text();
        //Pulls hidden div that includes "true" in the success response
        var response = text.substr(text.length - 4);

      if(response == "true"){
        $("#message").html('<a href="../login/main_login.php">Log in</a>');
        $('#submit').hide();
      }
```

this line `$("#message").html('<a href="../login/main_login.php">Log in</a>');`
 wont work i want to change it to link direct to the **`login.php`**

Comment: Can you provide HTML part for this code? Is #message element dynamically added or not?

Comment: can you tell us what is been coming in response ?? means value of html ... coming on success response

Comment: There are many possibilities. Check whether #message div exist only once in your page, check whether #message div is dynamically added or not, whether execution goes in if loop.